# Escaping back-references in recursive search

Tags: regex, vim

Is it possible to back-reference the result of an outer `:g` command in a recursive call (or an inner `:s` call?)

For instance, let's say I want to search for something above the cursor, and modify it when it appears below the cursor:

```
:1,.g/Hello, \(\w\+\)!/.,$s/\1/\1-San
```

This should replace:

```
Hello, Luciano!

Goodbye, Luciano!
```

with

```
Hello, Luciano!

Goodbye, Luciano-San!
```

If you place the cursor on the empty line.

However, it complains about an invalid back-reference. This is in reference to the last `\1` <s>(note that , maybe surprisingly the first `\1` in the search pattern -but not the replacement - works!)</s>. The reason is likely that the `:s` expression does not have any capture groups.

So my question is, whether there is a way to 'escape' the inner context of the command to execute in `:g`  to be able to `back-reference` a match group from the outer g?

(I appreciate there are other ways to achieve the desired effect in the above contrived example - but my question relates specifically to escaping back references, not writing a better regex - the example here is just for illustration)

Comment: No. `:g` and the commands executed as part of `:g` each have their own "pattern space", so to speak, so you can't capture a group in the former and reuse it in the latter.

Comment: @romainl it seems that you can use it in the search pattern  to `:s` like the first `\1` in the example I gave. That's what made me think it may be possible to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back references can be used within a search pattern:

```
before: xoxoxo foobarfoo xoxoxo

/\(foo\)bar\1

after: xoxoxo foobarfoo xoxoxo
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

as well as in the replacement part of a substitution:

```
before: xoxoxo foobarfoo xoxoxo

:s/\(foo\)bar\1/baz\1baz

after: xoxoxo bazfoobaz xoxoxo
```

This is possible because the capture group and the back reference occupy the same "pattern space" in a single atomic "command".

When you do `:g/<pattern>/<cmd>`, `<cmd>` is a separate "command" that doesn't share `:g`'s "pattern space" so it is impossible to reference a capture group from `<pattern>` in `<cmd>`.

What is possible, though, is to reuse `<pattern>` in `<cmd>`:

```
:g/\(foo\)bar\1/s//baz\1baz
```

but you are still not referencing a capture group from `:g` in `:s` even if it looks like it. You are making a new search with the same pattern and referencing the capture group in that new search.